# Check and open app from browser

Tags: ios9, deep-linking, ios9.2, ios-universal-links

I have been researching this from a while that if there is a concrete way has come through which a user can open any of the three apps from browser. Here I am trying to explain:

1. user opens a link on browser which has a button
2. user clicks on that button
3. Web page business login search for three apps: Yelp, Google+ and Facebook.
4. If yelp is found on the device, that opens if not then Google+ opens and if Google+ is also not installed, facebook opens and if all three are not installed then that page redirects to another webpage.

While searching for its solution I found that this can be done with `javascript's` `window.location` with a timer but that is not a good solution, then somewhere I found this video and they are doing exactly the same thing that I want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7jtlgx7uQU

I also observed that iOS 9.2's universal link can be helpful in this approach but could not found any suitable article how to use universal link on a webpage, I only found articles related to **how to implement universal link in an app**

I would be greatful to anyone who helps me.